# How is DS used in the case of Payment Gateways?

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, data-analysis, parameter, methods

I know it's a general question but what type of analytics can be done in this case?
How can we apply machine learning models here?

Answer (score 2):

Common use cases include:

1. Fraud detection
2. Transactions volume prediction
3. Next transaction date

## Fraud detection

This is usually tackled with [anomaly detection](https://blogs.oracle.com/datascience/introduction-to-anomaly-detection).

It requires information on the two transaction parties and using machine learning to figure out when a transaction is out of the norm and flagging as a potential case of fraud.

## Transactions volume prediction

This is usually tackled with [time-series forecasting](https://towardsdatascience.com/an-overview-of-time-series-forecasting-models-a2fa7a358fcb).

The idea is to predict the amount of transaction that will be done in the next day/week/month for a large amount of users. It requires seasonal information and, in case you have a lot of C2B transactions, analysis on major business.

## Next transaction date

This is also usually tackled with time-series forecasting. However, this analysis can be done on individual levels and not necessarily on a group of users.

The idea is to predict the date that the next transaction will be executed. This can be useful because there are cases where users will perform a lot of transactions in a short period of time, which could may be grouped together.